# How to calculate angles in a parallelogram?

Tags: geometry

I have this parallelogram. How can I calculate the angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, and $\theta$?

[image]

Comment: @peterwhy but why?

Comment: $\alpha+\beta$ is given. $\theta+\gamma$ follow from a property of parallelograms. $\alpha+\gamma$ are two angles in a triangle and you know the third, and ditto for $\beta+\theta$.